# Various [angular-*] tag(s) hover tooltips are broken in Firefox

Tags: bug, tags, design

I have just noticed (and [had another user confirm](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/55670178#55670178)) that certain Angular tags are not showing their tooltip (which shows number of followers, number of questions, and the first part of the Tag Wiki Excerpt) upon hover when using Firefox:

- [angular-cdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-cdk)
- [angular-cdk-drag-drop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-cdk-drag-drop)
- [angular-material](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-material)
- [angular-material2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-material2)
- [angular-material-5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-material-5)
- [angular-material-6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-material-6)
- [angular-material-7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-material-7)
- [angular-material-15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-material-15)
- [angular-material-table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-material-table)

I have not checked to find an exhaustive list of affected tags, but basically if the tag starts with "angular-" in it, the hover functionality appears to be broken. I did confirm that they still work fine in Chrome.

I don't know why this is occurring, but if the site uses Angular, it could be causing a conflict somehow.

Tested in Firefox 107 on Windows and Firefox 102ESR on Debian. Not sure yet what platform the Firefox 102 ESR user is on.

Comment: Example? *"angular-cdk"* on [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74721474/i-cant-extends-cdkscrollable-in-my-angular-library)?

Comment: OK, from the reference, [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-material), e.g. *"angular-cdk"* near *"Problem changing a default variable in Angular Material"*.

Comment: Firefox version 107.0 (Ubuntu. Minimum [JavaScript allowed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NoScript)): on hover, *"30 watchers. 609 questions. Use this tag for questions concerning your own components using the Angular CDK (Component DevKit) or Angular Material components that depend on the Angular CDK's APIs, like the MatTable. [View tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/angular-cdk). Watch tag. Ignore tag."*

Comment: @PeterMortensen Go to the question list for any of those tags mentioned in the question and hover over them while in Firefox. For me, no tooltip appears. Open the same pages in Chrome and the tooltips appear. Meanwhile, non-"Angular-*" tags have no issue with functionality. The issue persists when trying to hover over the tags while on a specific question page, too.

Comment: I will specify, I'm on Windows, so it's good info to learn it seems to work for you on Ubuntu.

Comment: [My Firefox setup](https://pmortensen.eu/world2/2022/06/29/setting-up-firefox-on-a-new-system/), but I don't think it makes a difference.

Comment: @PeterMortensen To be clear, do you _not_ see the behavior I've reported here? You haven't actually said one way or the other.

Comment: I can reproduce it - hovering on any tag that starts with `angular` does not do anything. Checking the network tab, it says it's blocked by uBlock origin. Checking the addon's logger says it's matched by a filter rule for `/tags/angular-` which, at least in my case, it's part of the EasyPrivacy list.

Comment: No repro on Firefox 107.0.1 on macOS Ventura. Tag popovers appear fine including angular-* tags (both logged in and logged out)

Comment: The popop works for me. It shows [all the expected information](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422032/various-angular-tags-hover-tooltips-are-broken-in-firefox#comment938482_422032) (I presume).

Comment: @VLAZ: Good catch! It looks like uBlock Origin (or a similar adblocker) is indeed the cause of this issue for anyone experiencing it; disabling it caused the tooltip to appear the next time I hovered over one of these tags on SO (even without reloading the SO page).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This seems to be an issue with adblocking. In my case, the blocking rule was part of EasyPrivacy list, but it also might be part of others. The rule it blocks anything with `/tags/angular-` in the request URL. I found [a website for the list](https://easylist.to/index.html) (it also includes related ones), but there is no information why the entry was added.

### How to identify adblocking

The first clue would be by opening the browser developer tools then checking the network tab.

Firefox directly states it was blocked by an extension ([uBlock Origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UBlock_Origin) in my case)

[image: Screenshot showing the Network tab in the Firefox developer tools. There is a request which is marked in red and in the column "Transferred" it says "Blocked by uBlock Origin"]

While Chrome is more laconic and just says it was "(blocked:other)".

[image: Screenshot showing the Network tab in the Chrome developer tools. There is a request which is marked in red and in the column "Status" it says "(blocked:other)"]

With that at least it is clear something happens, but it is prevented from happening.

To examine further, check the adblocking extension. Mine is uBlock origin, but most would work similarly, however, the menus and options might be in different places.

1. Open the logger by clicking the extension icon, and then the icon at the bottom:

   [image: Screenshot of the menu shown when clicking the uBlock Origin extension icon in Firefox. At the bottom there are five buttons, the fourth one has a tooltip "Open the logger"]
2. With the log open, you should cause an action that will lead to a blocked request, so it can be captured in the log. In this case, it is hovering over the tag, but in other cases might be reloading the page or opening a popup or others. The log will show requests and the blocked ones will be shown in red and the first column filled in with the filter rule which was matched.

   [image: Screenshot of the uBlock Origin logger. There are three requests logged. The one logged in read shows "/tags/angular-" at the start of the row. At the end of the row the URL is "https://stackoverflow.com/tags/angular-material/popup?_=1670657240442" with the part "/tags/angular-" highlighted.]
3. Clicking on initial part of the row will open up more details about the blocked request:

   [image: Screenshot showing the details of the blocked request It shows the filter was "/tags/angular-" and the filter list was "EasyPrivacy]

### Disable the rule

#### Teach a man how to fish

The most straightforward way to add an exception to a rule is:

1. from details of the blocked request to go to "Static filter"

   [image: Static filter tab on the details of the blocked request. Shows controls that can build up a filtering rule.]
2. Change

   - the "Block" to "Allow"
   - the "which URL the address matches" to something that will allow all such requests. Here just changing to the base URL of "stackoverflow.com" is sufficient

     [image: Static filter tab on the details of the blocked request. The dropdown that said "Block" was changed to "Allow" and the dropdown that listed the full URL is changed to "stackoverflow.com"]
   - you will see the generated exception rule at the bottom
3. Click "Create" which will add the exception to the local list of rules.

Alternatively, check the documentation on how to write filters yourself. However, I find the UI option easier.

- [How to write filters](https://help.adblockplus.org/hc/en-us/articles/360062733293) by Adblock Plus. Covers everything about common syntax and how to write all of the rules.
- [How to create your own ad filters](https://kb.adguard.com/en/general/how-to-create-your-own-ad-filters) article by AdGuard which covers the same topic.
- [Static filter syntax](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Static-filter-syntax) which goes over things specific for uBlock Origin.

#### Give fish

The filter needed is

```
@@||stackoverflow.com^$xhr,1p
```

It will allow first-party XHR requests when on stackoverflow.com

To add it directly to your list of rules:

1. Open the settings by clicking the extension icon, then the icon at the bottom:

   [image: Screenshot of the menu shown when clicking the uBlock Origin extension icon in Firefox. At the bottom there are five buttons, the fifth one has a tooltip "Open the dashboard"]
2. Navigate to "My filters" tab.
3. Add the filter rule as just a new line below.
4. Click "Apply changes"

   [image: Screenshot of the "My filters" tab in the uBlock Origin settings. It shows the results of steps 2., 3., and 4.]

Comment: Hmm, I explicitly disabled uBlock Origin and refreshed the page to test, and the issue still occurred, otherwise I wouldn't have posted the question. Maybe the behavior was cached somehow, I'll try again.

Comment: Could be another addon. Also if you're using some sort of network level filtering of ads, it might be killing the request at the DNS. Check the network tab for some guidance.

Comment: With a fresh session and cache and disabling uBlock Origin, it works correctly for me. Weird...

Comment: I've noticed somehow that disabling the adblocking addons isn't enough. It's hard to reproduce, though. My best guess there is that it's a bug with Firefox and the addon system. Perhaps addons some times stay active or somehow "stuck" even if disabled. Stopping the addon and restarting FF seems to work in those cases. But not sure which part.

Comment: Please file a bug if you think there's a bug. :) https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/enter_bug.cgi?format=guided#h=dupes|WebExtensions|

Comment: @zcorpan I don't have enough information. No reproduction steps, either. I've just experienced this behaviour few times but I can't even be sure if it's something with the addons I have or specifically with FF.